# No input file specified in laravel Spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to save laravel database backup, my cron command is:

```
cd /home/user/foldername/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /home/user/cron.out
```

Kernel:

```
 $schedule->command('backup:clean')->daily()->everyMinute();
 $schedule->command('backup:run')->daily()->everyMinute();
```

when cron is run i get

> No input file specified. Status: 404 Not Found X-Powered-By:
> PHP/7.3.26 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

in the cron.out file, I have saved public folder content in public_html folder rest of the files are in root.

Comment: Please share the command that is having the issue

Comment: @apokryfos: I have updated my question can you please check

Comment: Do the commands `php artisan backup:clean` and `php artisan backup:run` work as expected?

Comment: @apokryfos: yes they are working when i run it on terminal